# Change the logical name of sql server express 2005 database file?

Tags: sql-server-2005

In Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio Express for Sql Server Express 2005, I needed to copy a database for testing and keep it on the same server as the old database.  I did the following:

1. Right Click on Databases
2. Created new database
3. Detached the database I wanted to copy
4. "Restored" my new database from the backup file of my old database.  I did this by clicking the 'Overwrite the existing database' box on the Options pane, and I changed the paths in the 'restore as' options so that they pointed to my new .mdf and .ldf files.

Everything is working like I want.  Problem is, when I right-click -> Properties -> Files on my new database, the logical name of the .mdf file is the same as the logical name of the old .mdf file.  They are actually different files - they just share the same logical name?

I guess maybe this isn't a short-term problem, but I can see it confusing somebody down the road.  Any way to change the logical name of the .mdf file?

UPDATE EDIT - Apparently you can just change the logical name through the GUI by, get this, clicking on it and typing a new name.  I could swear that was not possible when I posted this, but maybe it was and I somehow missed it!  Either way - the solution below should still work but doing it through the GUI is also an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logical filename is an identifier for SQL's internal purposes.  It abstracts the actual physical filename so that you can relocate the physical file without having to change a bunch of things inside SQL.

To change the logical name of a file do this:

```
ALTER DATABASE <Database name>
MODIFY FILE  ( NAME = <current_logical_name>, NEWNAME = <new_logical_name>)
```

Have a look at [**this article**](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/814576) for more on info on consolidating and renaming files.